# What is current advice on forwarding email - particularly to gmail

Tags: linux, postfix, mail-forwarding

I want to move from my current hosting site to a VPS. I am very comfortable with the website hosting side of things but at the moment my stumbling block is email, something which I have never had to deal with before. Outbound is fine, I have set up postfix with TLS and have SPF, DKIM and DMARC configured and all seems to work fine. However, on my existing site I have 5 email addresses for different domain names that I currently forward, 4 of them to gmail accounts. Volumes are trivial, an average of less than one a day - between all 5!

I have seen advice that says don't forward email because of potential problems with spam and being blacklisted because my server would appear to be the origin of the spam.

To avoid this problem [(here)](https://support.google.com/a/answer/175365?hl=en) Google says "do not change the envelope sender when forwarding email to Gmail". If I use virtual alias maps in Postfix I am assuming that this would change the envelope sender to be my server? Is there a way of not changing the envelope sender? And if I could do it, wouldn't it then fail SPF checks?

Should I be using postsrsd? Does this change the headers in such a way that it satisfies Gmail whilst not breaking SPF.

I have seen a variety of advice out there but much of it seems dated and often assumes a level of knowledge I don't yet have. I would appreciate any advice, preferably not "don't do it"! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience using 3rd parties to forward email, I did find that Gmail marked many emails as spam. It's better to avoid that risk altogether. I've had much better deliverability since I set up a pop3 server for Gmail to fetch mail from. There is a delay since it polls, so for some emails like password resets it's important to be able to access that mailbox directly.

Comment: I have seen this approach recommended elsewhere but I couldn't find out how it worked in practice. I thought that it might only pull the emails in if you accessed gmail directly through the browser and not if you were using a client and imap. However you say that it polls so that makes it a viable option. Thanks.